# Checking for group membership

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have been running around like crazy trying to get this working correctly, but it seems as if it refuses to. All examples I have found on the web look pretty much like this with a difference of how the PrincipalContext, UserPrincipal, and GroupPrincipal are declared. Some are declared by a function that returns the object, others just do it directly. The frustrating part for me is that when I run this bit of code:

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext(sDefaultRootOU);
            UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sUserName);
            GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, sGroupName);

            bool isUserGroupMember = oUserPrincipal.IsMemberOf(oGroupPrincipal);
```

No matter what I do, isUserGroupMember always comes back as false, EVEN IF the user in question IS a member of the group. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update** This is wild, however I have managed to isolate the issue down to one group, the Domain Users group, I have verified this against other 'built in' AD groups, and the membership shows correctly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a complete answer, it seems as if the 'Domain Users' group is the only one that returns this result, regardless of membership. Seeing as all users are members of that group by default I just wrote a line in there to disregard the group if the group specified is 'Domain Users'